# How to get path to the ImageIcon?

Tags: java, image, path, get, icons

I created ImageIcon like this:

```
ImageIcon ico =new ImageIcon("tree.png");
```

Now, it's possible to get this path to string?

```
String path = ico.get ? ( ? );
```

Comment: not clear, be much more specific please

Answer (score -2):

Try the `getDescription()` method of the `ImageIcon` class.

Don't think it works in all cases, for example if you create the ImageIcon with an Image, but it should work when you specify the file name/path.